# How can I control VLC instance with threading

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, vlc, libvlc

I'm new to Python so I'm doing everything by tutorials and codes I find online and I have this problem that I'm trying to solve for some time without any luck. I hope my description will be at least somewhat understandable because I really don't understand the problem much myself...

I have 2 files, each has one class made with OOP.
The mainfile.py and its class is for taking user input and looking for and selecting song from mysql database, then it runs the music file and its music class as a new thread and passes the song name. The music file/class sets up the vlc media player (python-vlc) and then plays the selected song.

`self.newInstance = vlc.Instance()`
`self.player = self.newInstance.media_player_new()`

Now it returs to the main file which expects another user input, which is "stop music". This runs the music_stop method in the music file/class.

`self.player.stop()`

The problem is it has no effect. The music is still playing. My thought is that its because when it runs the music class again to run the music_stop method, it creates new instance and new mediaplayer (which isn't playing anything) and is trying to stop it.. not the first instance which is actually playing the song.

I hope its not too confusing. Plase ask questions if you need to because I'm pretty sure there is something that I forgot to mention. I'll provide additional info as needed.

Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it literally in few minutes after I posted this question... and after 4 days of struggling with it.
The solution was to make the file without class and so without OOP. Now it works.